# Use grep to write in file gpspipe data

Tags: command-line

I am trying to use the gpspipe tool to create a file output of latitude and longitude data. All I am interested only "GPRMC" NMEA  messages so I have constructed the current line of code isolating the GPPA lines (which have this info).

```
gpspipe -r -t -o test.txt | grep "GPRMC"
```

I can see the correct output in monitor when I run `gpspipe -r -t |grep  "GPRMC"` and I save output in file when I run `gpspipe -r -t  > gpsoutput.txt`.After the  command: gpspipe -r -t > gpsoutput.txt the file gpsoutput.txt is
`2024-03-25 08:21:10: {"class":"VERSION","release":"3.20","rev":"3.20","proto_major":3,"proto_minor":14} 2024-03-25 08:21:10: {"class":"DEVICES","devices":[{"class":"DEVICE","path":"/dev/ttyACM0","driver":"u-blox","subtype":"SW EXT CORE 1.00 (0fa0ae),HW 00190000","subtype1":",ROM BASE 0x118B2060,FWVER=HPG 1.32,PROTVER=27.31,MOD=ZED-F9P,GPS;GLO;GAL;BDS,SBAS;QZSS","activated":"2024-03-25T08:21:10.000Z","flags":1,"native":1,"bps":9600,"parity":"N","stopbits":1,"cycle":1.00,"mincycle":0.25}]} 2024-03-25 08:21:10: {"class":"WATCH","enable":true,"json":false,"nmea":true,"raw":0,"scaled":false,"timing":false,"split24":false,"pps":false} 2024-03-25 08:21:11: $GPZDA,082110.00,25,03,2024,00,00*6C 2024-03-25 08:21:11: $GPGGA,082110.00,4601.0178,N,01154.2363,E,1,24,0.72,268.29,M,42.674,M,,*69 2024-03-25 08:21:11: $GPRMC,082110.00,A,4601.0178,N,01154.2363,E,0.1147,61.965,250324,3.3,E*56`

. When I run `gpspipe -r -t |grep  "GPRMC" > gpsoutput.txt` the file is empty... Why? How do I do?

Comment: possibility that the data encoding gpspipe output, does not correspond to which grep matched, check encoding with `file` command :$ ```gpspipe -r -t | file -```

Comment: When I run `gpspipe -r -t | file - ` I have no results. How do I do? Thank you in advance

Comment: share file gpsoutput.txt, result run this command: regpspipe -r -t  > gpsoutput.txt

Comment: The `-o test.txt` option probably means the output is not sent to standard output. At this point the least implausible explanation is that you forgot to take this out, even though you imply in your question that you did.

Comment: I've tried both with the -o option and without but nothing is written to the file. How can I do?